# How to add date stamp when criteria met in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, javascript

This is the current script. When a cell in column 26 is edited, a datestamp is added to the cell beside it in column 27. Now I would like to add additional criteria. Example: When col 26 value is "Text" then col 27 date stamp.

Can anyone help me plz.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e)
{
  var startRow = 3;
  var targetColumn = 26;
  var ws = "START";
  var currentDate = new Date();
 
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === 26 && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws)
  {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,27).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already using [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).

- One of the available objects is "value" (New cell value after the edit. Only available if the edited range is a single cell).

Your `IF` statement already has three (3) criteria, so just add another. Something like:

`if(col === 26 && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws && e.value ===  "Text"){`